# Excel: How to nest if and count if statements?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to check if cell O3 is contained in list A7:A11, and if so, return cell G2. I'm using the following formula to do this, and it works:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$7:$A$11,"*"&O3&"*"),$G$2,"")
```

However, I want to add another of these, to check multiple lists e.g.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$7:$A$11,"*"&O3&"*"),$G$2,"") , IF(COUNTIF($A$12:$A$14,"*"&O3&"*"),$G$7,"")
```

but this does not work (I can't successfully nest these statements, I tried using OR but this also failed)

So, I want to check if cell 03 is contained in list A7:A11 and if so, return G2, but also, if cell 03 is contained in list A12:A14, return G7 and so forth.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF($A$7:$A$11,"*"&O3&"*"),$G$2,"")&IF(COUNTIF($A$12:$A$14,"*"&O3&"*"),$G$7,"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner You beautiful specimen thank-you!